# Rails model for storing only constant attributes and translations for them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We need for our project a "model" (doesn't necessarily have to be a model) where we can store constants attributes (they won't change and can be hardcoded) and also translations for them. We could've used a database to store these attributes, but since they won't change, it's a bit overkill.

The approach we've taken is to define all these attributes in the translations file, `en.yml`, then wherever we need them, we would iterate over the specific translation key: `I18n.t('attributes').each do ... end`.

But this feels as if it's not the best solution. I guess it's a pretty common scenario, so where should we store these constant attributes and how should we use them?

Comment: you can put them in lib folder when ever you need them just require the file in your controller or model and user them.This works for me as i put all my regex there.

Comment: And what about the translations?

Answer (score 0):

create a file constent.rb in your lib folder.

```
module Constent
   # your code goes here.....
end
```

and in your application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

and in your controller or model use

```
include Constent
```

Comment: I don't want to autoload my whole lib folder. Also, how should I handle translations in this case?